# useEffect does not store state for Firebase data on initial load and only shows up after fast refresh

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks, next.js

## UPDATE

@Chris's answer below helped me with my issue. Installed the [React Firebase Hooks](https://github.com/CSFrequency/react-firebase-hooks) package and set up my code as seen below. Everything is working flawlessly now! :)

```ts
const [value] = useCollection(collection(db, `${sessionUserId}`), {
    snapshotListenOptions: { includeMetadataChanges: true },
  })
  useEffect(() => {
    if (value) {
      const allData = JSON.parse(
        JSON.stringify(
          value?.docs.map((doc) => ({
            id: doc.id as string,
            resultData: doc.data() as DocumentData,
          }))
        )
      )
      setAllLogs(allData)
    }
  }, [value])
```

---

**What am I using in my project?** NextAuthjs, Firebase, Recoiljs

I have a useRecoilState hook to save logs that users have created.

```ts
const [allLogs, setAllLogs] = useRecoilState(modalAllLogs)
```

The `modalAllLogs` looks like this:

```ts
export const modalAllLogs = atom<Array<DocumentData>>({
  key: 'allLogs',
  default: [],
})
```

Here is the issue. I have a useEffect hook that grabs the data the user has from the database and assigns `setAllLogs` to that data. *Note: I * do not * have the state updating anywhere else.*

```ts
useEffect(() => {
    const docQuery = query(
      collection(db, `${sessionUserId}`),
      orderBy('timestamp', 'desc')
    )
    const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(
      docQuery,
      (snapshot: QuerySnapshot<DocumentData>) => {
        const data = JSON.parse(
          JSON.stringify(
            snapshot.docs.map((doc: QueryDocumentSnapshot<DocumentData>) => ({
              id: doc.id as string,
              resultData: doc.data() as DocumentData,
            }))
          )
        )
        setAllLogs(data)
      }
    )
    return unsubscribe
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [db])
```

What happens is, on **initial render**, `allLogs` returns an empty array, which makes sense, but stays empty until I make any edit within the same file the useEffect hook is in, save it, and NextJS triggers it's **fast render**, only then does `allLogs` suddenly display the data properly. I did a `console.log(snapshot)` and it is empty on every **initial render** as well.

Whenever I add data using the inputs I have created, Firebase stores all the data properly and correctly. The only issue is when the data is not loaded in on **initial render**. Other than that, I have no other issues.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. Maybe it is the `RecoilState` that I am utilizing wrong?

I have tried many things from other forums - changing the dependency to allLogs (which gave me an infinite loop), tried using `getDocs()` instead of `onSnapshot()`, and etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is, that the useEffect isn't triggered because the "db" constant doesn't change.

Have a look at these custom hooks for Firebase/firestore https://github.com/CSFrequency/react-firebase-hooks/tree/master/firestore
or lift the onSnapshot up to get real-time results. But in the last case the renders won't be triggered so I think it's the best to make use of custom hooks.

Comment: But `useEffect` shouldn't trigger more than once here

Comment: @Chris Okay I understand what you are saying but even if I change db to anything else, it also doesn't work. Do you have any resource for how real-time results look without the onSnapshot?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski I am trying to have the state update every time it is updated.

Comment: @Ariel I send you the resource in the link above. useEffect() will only re-trigger when one of the entries in the dependency array `[db]` changes. but the instance doesn't change because it's a reference. So a custom hook will be necessary, otherwise, no re-rendering is triggered.

Comment: @Chris You, my friend, are a life saver. I figured it out and updated my question with what I did. Been at this for 2 days and didn't even know there was as simple of a solution as the one you gave. Thank you!!